# How to write a code for an 'Alert popup' in a web application which does not require any accept or decline condition

Tags: selenium-webdriver, alert

How to write a code for an 'Alert popup' in a web application which does not require any accept or decline condition. Just to check the popup is displaying and it will automatically vanishes after 2 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Can you add the (minimal amount of) code to reproduce this behavior and show what you've done to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any text content in the popup?if so try to get the text element as reference and decide the visibility of the toast/popup

Answer (score 0):

you can wait until the alert is presented. you can write something like this:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  System.out.println("Alert text:"+alert.getText());
```